# To assign variable from a file separated by delimiter

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a text file with datas as below separated by delimiter:

```
1000:Tom:user1
1002:Jerry:user2
1003:Victor:user3
1004:Jason:user4
```

I need to run a while loop (any loop) to fetch details from first line and assign variable as below:

```
uid:1000
username:Tom
userid:user1
```

This script should be able to collect details till the end of file "data". I can do this part once I am able to do for the first line.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `awk` you can do something like

```
while IFS=: read -r uid username userid; do
  printf "user:%s\nusername:%s\nuserid:%s\n" "$uid" "$username" "$userid"; 
done <file 
user:1000
username:Tom
userid:user1
user:1002
username:Jerry
userid:user2
user:1003
username:Victor
userid:user3
user:1004
username:Jason
userid:user4
```

`IFS` is the input record separator, by setting it to `:` you can read the variables from the file directly.

Answer (score 3):

See the below awk script:

```
user@host:~# awk -F: '{printf "uid:%s\nusername:%s\nuserid:%s\n", $1,$2,$3}' file
uid:1000
username:Tom
userid:user1
uid:1002
username:Jerry
userid:user2
uid:1003
username:Victor
userid:user3
uid:1004
username:Jason
userid:user4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `cat text_file`;do uid=`echo "$i"|cut -d: -f1`; username=`echo "$i"|cut -d: -f2`; userid=`echo "$i"|cut -d: -f3`; echo "uid=$uid,username=$username,userid=$userid";done

uid=1000,username=Tom,userid=user1
uid=1002,username=Jerry,userid=user2
uid=1003,username=Victor,userid=user3
uid=1004,username=Jason,userid=user4
```

So you have variables `$uid`, `$username`, `$userid` to use.

Is that good?